# 'make' not recognized as internal or external command while executing npm test for mocha testing in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Getting following problem while executing mocha npm test

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. npm ERR! weird error 1 npm ERR! not ok code 0

```
makefile:
 test:
   ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
     --reporter list

 .PHONY: test

package.json

{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "make test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.3.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongoose": ">= 2.6.5",
    "nodemailer": "0.3.20",
    "connect": ">= 1.9.1",
    "socket.io": "~0.9",
    "cookie": "0.0.4",
    "kue" : "*",
    "async" : "*",
    "mocha": "*",
    "should" : "*",
    "winston" : "*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't have make installed. Are you on Windows?

But, you don't need and shouldn't use make to run tests. Instead, add the following at the bottom of your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -R list",
  }
```

Now, you can run tests by simply entering `npm test`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. yes I am on windows and was trying to use Make...1 more problem I am getting, i have sub directories in my test directory, test works only if keep test file in test folder, how can I change these Mocha settings

Comment: You can specify a list of folders for mocha, such as `mocha -R spec server/test/large server/test/medium server/test/small`.